# How to remove one string if its repeated one after another?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a string like `test||test`.

Here in this string the `|` is repeating after the same string `|`. So in this case I want to remove one so that I should get it as `test|test`.

Is this possible through jquery.

Comment: jQuery isn't needed here; it's primarily a DOM manipulation tool. This can be done in plain old JS: `str.replace('||', '|');`

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. why it didn't come in mind first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way
$( "||" ).replaceAll( "|" );
you can see the complete example in this link
[jquery](https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/)